# F# record member evaluation

Tags: f#, record, member

Why is t.b evaluated on every call? And is there any way how to make it evaluate only once?

```
type test =
  { a: float }
  member x.b =
    printfn "oh no"
    x.a * 2.

let t = { a = 1. }
t.b
t.b
```

Comment: It is disappointing that the F# language does not support one-time-calculated-values for immutable records. I suppose the complication is if `a` is flagged as mutable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a property; you're basically calling the `get_b()` member.

If you want the effect to happen once with the constructor, you could use a class:

```
type Test(a:float) =
    // constructor
    let b =   // compute it once, store it in a field in the class
        printfn "oh no"
        a * 2.
    // properties
    member this.A = a
    member this.B = b
```

Comment: You are right, but using classes I lose things like let c = {t with a = 4.}, right?

Comment: Yes, but you can write a constructor with optional parameters and get a very similar effect.

Comment: I do not get your idea. Imagine that I have a Record with constructor having 10 parameters like {a:float; b:float, c: float...}. Creating a new record from an old one is done as {old with c = 5}. How do I do the same with classes without rewriting all parameters in the constructor?

Answer (score 17):

An alternative version of Brian's answer that will evaluate `b` at most once, but won't evaluate it at all if `B` is never used

```
type Test(a:float) =
    // constructor
    let b = lazy
                 printfn "oh no"
                 a * 2.
    // properties
    member this.A = a
    member this.B = b.Value
```

Answer (score 4):

In response to your comments in Brian's post, you can fake copy-and-update record expressions using optional/named args. For example:

```
type Person(?person:Person, ?name, ?age) =

    let getExplicitOrCopiedArg arg argName copy =
        match arg, person with
        | Some(value), _ -> value
        | None, Some(p) -> copy(p)
        | None, None -> nullArg argName

    let name = getExplicitOrCopiedArg name "name" (fun p -> p.Name)
    let age = getExplicitOrCopiedArg age "age" (fun p -> p.Age)

    member x.Name = name
    member x.Age = age

let bill = new Person(name = "Bill", age = 20)
let olderBill = new Person(bill, age = 25)

printfn "Name: %s, Age: %d" bill.Name bill.Age
printfn "Name: %s, Age: %d" olderBill.Name olderBill.Age
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous responses suggest switching to a class, instead of using a record. If you want to stay with records (for their simple syntax and immutability), you can take this approach:

```
type test =
    { a : float
      b : float }
    static member initialize (t: test) =
        { t with b = t.a * 2. }
```

This is useful if the instance of `test` is created by another library (like a data provider from a web service or database). With this approach, you must remember to pass any instance of `test` that you receive from that API through the initialize function before using it in your code.

Comment: You can use a private constructor so you don't have to remember to call the initialize function. Scott Wlaschin has some examples here: https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/54cfff886669ccab895a